# How to import query reducer, removekey and other modules from admin-on-rest to custom list?

Tags: redux, react-redux, admin-on-rest, custom-lists

I am creating a custom List component by referring to admin-on-rest List component. I imported all modules from admin-on-rest. But few modules are not getting imported and giving an error like queryreducer,removeKey ...

What is the correct way of importing modules from admin-on-rest?

i tried importing all modules at one place.
Also tried importing default and others separate

> admin-on-rest version : "1.2.3"

I tried this way :

```
import {
  queryReducer,
  SET_SORT,
  SET_PAGE,
  SET_FILTER,
  SORT_DESC,
  ViewTitle,
  Title,
  DefaultPagination,
  DefaultActions,
  crudGetList as crudGetListAction,
  changeListParams as changeListParamsAction,
  removeKey,
  defaultTheme
} from "admin-on-rest";

and also this way :

import { SET_SORT, SET_PAGE, SET_FILTER, SORT_DESC } from "admin-on-rest";

import { queryReducer } from "admin-on-rest";

import { ViewTitle } from "admin-on-rest";

import Title from "admin-on-rest";

import DefaultPagination from "admin-on-rest";

import DefaultActions from "admin-on-rest";

import { crudGetList as crudGetListAction } from "admin-on-rest";

import { changeListParams as changeListParamsAction } from "admin-on-rest";

import translate from "admin-on-rest";

import { removeKey } from "admin-on-rest";

import defaultTheme from "admin-on-rest";
```

**The output error  :**

> Uncaught TypeError: **webpack_require**.i(...) is not a function

Answer (score 0):

```
I made it working by importing like this. Just specify the exact path.

import {
  SET_SORT,
  SET_PAGE,
  SET_FILTER,
  SORT_DESC
} from "admin-on-rest/lib/reducer/resource/list/queryReducer";
import queryReducer from "admin-on-rest/lib/reducer/resource/list/queryReducer";
import removeKey from "admin-on-rest/lib/util/removeKey";
```